# Given nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $f$, how is $L_f(x) = f(x,-)$ defined for $x = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $f$ be a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form over an $n$-dimensional vector space $X$. For each nonzero vector $x \in X$, define the dual vector
$$f(x,-) \in X^{\prime}, \hspace{3mm} f(x,-): y \mapsto f(x,y).$$
Now we define $L_f:X \rightarrow X^{\prime}$ by $L_f: x\mapsto f(x,-)$.

**Questions.** Since $L_f$ is defined for all vectors in $X$, then what does $L_f$ do with $x = 0$? The only way I understand the definition of $L_f$ is that it maps nonzero vectors to $f(x,-)$, which makes sense because $f(x,-)$ was constructed using nonzero vectors. Is it somehow implied that $L_f$ maps $0$ by $0$?

Answer (score 1):

The map $L_f:X\to X'$ is linear, so it maps the zero vector of $X$ to the zero vector of $X'$, that is the zero linear map.

Another way to see this is to use linearity in $x$: For all $y\in X$, we have $f(0,y)=f(0+0,y)=f(0,y)+f(0,y)$. Substracting $f(0,y)$ on both sides yields $f(0,y)=0$.

PS. Your definition of $L_f$ works perfectly for $x=0$, I don't understand what is puzzling you.

Comment: I think I'm just really overthinking it. If $x$ is nonzero, then we construct $f(x,-)$. Ok, good. So this $f(x,-)$ works for nonzero $x$. But then we shift to $x\mapsto f(x,0)$ for every $x$. I'm puzzled at this point. If $x=0$, then how can I map it to $f(0,-)$? We just said that $f(x,-)$ was built from nonzero $x$, so what is $f(0,-)$? I think that's where the confusion arises about the $L_f$ definition.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why this particular function poses a problem?  Would you ask yourself the same question for any function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$  for example, for $f(x)=x^2?$